# Javascript: How to capture the height of the content of a website?

Tags: javascript, size, height, scroll

I am trying to find the correct Javascript code to capture the height of all the content on a webpage.

I have looked at document.height, window.screen.height, document.body.offsetHeight, bodyScroll, clientArea.style.height, bodyHeight, and document.documentElement.clientHeight.

I am using FireBug to test these values but all (except for the window.screen.height) seem to change as I resize my window, so they are not actual reporting the actual height of the content.

Now, the window.screen.height never changes, even if I change to different pages with different sizes.

How can I determine the total height of the content? Basically I need to know what the scroll bar knows. Th scrollbar knows how much to scroll per page and how much to scroll to reach the end of the content.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a library like jQuery or YUI. Otherwise copy the code in there in your own function but be prepared becasue it's a huge mess. `YAHOO.util.Dom.getDocumentHeight()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

document_height = $(document).height();
document_width = $(document).width();
window_height = $(window).height();
window_width = $(window).width();

alert(document_height + ' x ' + document_width);

alert(window_height + ' x ' + window_width);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Different browers report the size of the window and size of the document in different ways. You can use a library to get around the cross browser problems, like this code in jQuery:

```
$(document).height();
```

Without a library, I have used this code to get the dimensions:

```
var b, h, info;
b = document.body;
h = b.parentNode;
if (window.opera) {
  info = { winWidth: b.clientWidth, winHeight: b.clientHeight, pageWidth: h.clientWidth, pageHeight: h.clientHeight };
} else {
  info = { winWidth: h.clientWidth, winHeight: h.clientHeight, pageWidth: b.clientWidth, pageHeight: b.clientHeight };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var height = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
```